# How to filter the options using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to filter the options ...

when I am  selecting the city movie and theater drop down is coming after that I select the movie or theater to change the movie playing theater or theater play a movie................

if I selected the one option to show the option related information

below is my html code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var cityData = [{
      cityName: 'Bengaluru',
      value: "Bengaluru",
      data: [{
          movieName: 'ABC',
          theaterName: 'Tulsi Theatre'
        },
        {
          movieName: 'DEF',
          theaterName: 'PVR'
        },
        {
          movieName: 'GHI',
          theaterName: 'Srinivasa Theatre'
        }
      ]
    },


    {
      cityName: 'Hyderabad',
      value: "Hyderabad",
      data: [{
          movieName: '123',
          theaterName: 'Theatre1'
        },
        {
          movieName: '456',
          theaterName: 'PVR2'
        },
        {
          movieName: '789',
          theaterName: 'Theatre3'
        }
      ]
    },

    {
      cityName: 'Guntur',
      value: "Guntur",
      data: [{
          movieName: 'ABC1',
          theaterName: 'Theatre4'
        },
        {
          movieName: 'DEF2',
          theaterName: 'PVR3'
        },
        {
          movieName: 'GHI3',
          theaterName: 'Theatre5'
        }
      ]
    },

    {
      cityName: 'Ongole',
      value: "Ongole",
      data: 'currently not available'
    }
  ];

  $("#selectCity").on('change', function() {
    var locations = cityData.filter(c => c.cityName === $(this).val())[0].data;
    var locationString = '';
    var locationString2 = '';
    console.log(locations)
    $.each(locations, function(i, item) {

      console.log(JSON.stringify(item));
      locationString += '<option value="' + item.theaterName + '">' + item.theaterName + '</option>';
      locationString2 += '<option value="' + item.movieName + '">' + item.movieName + '</option>';
    });
    $('#secondselectbox').html(locationString);
    $('#thirdselectbox').html(locationString2);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="UserData">
  <h1>MyMovie-Ticket-Booking</h1>
  <select class="selectCity" id="selectCity">
    <option value="City">Select City</option>
    <option value="Bengaluru">Bengaluru</option>
    <option value="Hyderabad">Hyderabad</option>
    <option value="Guntur">Guntur</option>
    <option value="Ongole">Ongole</option>
  </select>
  <span id="welcome"> </span>
</div>
<div>
  <select id="secondselectbox"></select>
  <select id="thirdselectbox"></select>
</div>
```

How to change the when I selected the movie name in first drop down to change the related theater name in another drop down...

to change the movie name and show the theater where the movie is playing.....

Comment: @bipinpatel: No, that would be offsite. Live examples should be **on-site** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). [How to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha). (And live examples are optional, provided enough code is shown. Useful and helpful to encourage answers, but optional.)

Comment: Not 100% sure what you wanna fut if on one selection you have to filter another it's usually a good idea to instantiate another object/array from original selection that would be available for second selection, and filter out original selection to that array then bind options from that array. This way your original data is intact in case you shange 1st selection to something different

Comment: also, <option value="City">Select City</option> this option might break your logic of filtering. Its far safer to use value of undefined or null. You wanna this option to stand out and not be valid for form submission

Comment: Also I see city selection, not movie and theatre selections :/

Comment: @DanteTheSmith OP is already using `Array#filter()`

Comment: Really not clear what specific problem is

Comment: to select the city movie drop down and theater drop down is coming after that i select the movie name in drop down how to change the theater name where movie is playing

Comment: Edit the question to properly explain what the code is currently doing differently than is expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var cityData = [{
      cityName: 'Bengaluru',
      value: "Bengaluru",
      data: [{
          movieName: 'ABC',
          theaterName: 'Tulsi Theatre'
        },
        {
          movieName: 'DEF',
          theaterName: 'PVR'
        },
        {
          movieName: 'GHI',
          theaterName: 'Srinivasa Theatre'
        }
      ]
    },


    {
      cityName: 'Hyderabad',
      value: "Hyderabad",
      data: [{
          movieName: '123',
          theaterName: 'Theatre1'
        },
        {
          movieName: '456',
          theaterName: 'PVR2'
        },
        {
          movieName: '789',
          theaterName: 'Theatre3'
        }
      ]
    },

    {
      cityName: 'Guntur',
      value: "Guntur",
      data: [{
          movieName: 'ABC1',
          theaterName: 'Theatre4'
        },
        {
          movieName: 'ABC1',
          theaterName: 'PVR3'
        },
        {
          movieName: 'GHI3',
          theaterName: 'Theatre5'
        }
      ]
    },

    {
      cityName: 'Ongole',
      value: "Ongole",
      data: 'currently not available'
    }
  ];
  $("#selectCity").on('change', function() {
    var locations = cityData.filter(c => c.cityName === $(this).val())[0].data;
    var locationString2 = '';
    console.log(locations)
    $.each(locations, function(i, item) {
        locationString2 += '<option value="' + item.movieName + '">' + item.movieName + '</option>';
    });
    $('#thirdselectbox').html(locationString2);
    createTheaterDropdown();
});
   $("#thirdselectbox").on('change', function() {
     createTheaterDropdown();

   });
   function createTheaterDropdown(){
     var locations = cityData.filter(c => c.cityName === $('#selectCity').val())[0].data;
      var movie = locations.filter(c => c.movieName === $('#thirdselectbox').val());
      var locationString = '';
      $.each(movie, function(i, item) {
        locationString += '<option value="' + item.theaterName + '">' + item.theaterName + '</option>';
      })

    $('#secondselectbox').html(locationString);
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>MyMovie-Ticket-Booking</h1>
  <select class="selectCity" id="selectCity">
                    <option value="City">Select City</option>
                    <option value="Bengaluru">Bengaluru</option>
                    <option value="Hyderabad">Hyderabad</option>
                    <option value="Guntur">Guntur</option>
                    <option value="Ongole">Ongole</option>
                </select>
  <span id="welcome"> </span>
</div>
<div>
  <select id="thirdselectbox"></select>
  <select id="secondselectbox"></select>
</div>
```

You can filter theater name after select city name here is code for that

```
$("#selectCity").on('change', function () {
    var locations = cityData.filter(c => c.cityName === $(this).val())[0].data;
    var locationString2 = '';
    console.log(locations)
    $.each(locations, function (i, item) {
        locationString2 += '<option value="' + item.movieName + '">' + item.movieName + '</option>';
    });
    $('#thirdselectbox').html(locationString2);
    createTheaterDropdown();
});
$("#thirdselectbox").on('change', function () {
    createTheaterDropdown();

});

function createTheaterDropdown() {
    var locations = cityData.filter(c => c.cityName === $('#selectCity').val())[0].data;
    var movie = locations.filter(c => c.movieName === $('#thirdselectbox').val());
    var locationString = '';
    $.each(movie, function (i, item) {
        locationString += '<option value="' + item.theaterName + '">' + item.theaterName + '</option>';
    })

    $('#secondselectbox').html(locationString);
}
```

Comment: one doubt if i select the movie name to change the movie play on that theater how to do that one?

Comment: use `append` instead of `html` if you want to preserve any event bindings on the movies. If you don't have any then don't worry about it.

Comment: and `cityData.filter(...)[0].data` should be `cityData.find(...).data`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can ensure each movie is associated to the theater by adding a custom attribute, i.e: `data-theater=item.theaterName`.

Then you can use the change event of the theater dropdown to hide/show the relevant movies instead of continuously re-building the DOM.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var cityData = [{
      cityName: 'Bengaluru',
      value: "Bengaluru",
      data: [{
          movieName: 'ABC',
          theaterName: 'Tulsi Theatre'
        },
        {
          movieName: 'DEF',
          theaterName: 'PVR'
        },
        {
          movieName: 'GHI',
          theaterName: 'Srinivasa Theatre'
        }
      ]
    },


    {
      cityName: 'Hyderabad',
      value: "Hyderabad",
      data: [{
          movieName: '123',
          theaterName: 'Theatre1'
        },
        {
          movieName: '456',
          theaterName: 'PVR2'
        },
        {
          movieName: '789',
          theaterName: 'Theatre3'
        }
      ]
    },

    {
      cityName: 'Guntur',
      value: "Guntur",
      data: [{
          movieName: 'ABC1',
          theaterName: 'Theatre4'
        },
        {
          movieName: 'DEF2',
          theaterName: 'PVR3'
        },
        {
          movieName: 'GHI3',
          theaterName: 'Theatre5'
        }
      ]
    },

    {
      cityName: 'Ongole',
      value: "Ongole",
      data: 'currently not available'
    }
  ];

  $("#selectCity").on('change', function() {
    var locations = cityData.filter(c => c.cityName === $(this).val())[0].data;
    var locationString = '';
    var locationString2 = '';
    console.log(locations)
    $.each(locations, function(i, item) {

      console.log(JSON.stringify(item));
      locationString += '<option value="' + item.theaterName + '">' + item.theaterName + '</option>';
      locationString2 += '<option data-theater="' + item.theaterName + '" value="' + item.movieName + '">' + item.movieName + '</option>';
    });
    $('#secondselectbox').append(locationString);
    $('#thirdselectbox').append(locationString2);
    
    // ensure the movies are initialized correctly based on the current theater
    theaterChanged.call($('#secondselectbox'));
  });

  $("#secondselectbox").on('change', theaterChanged);

  function theaterChanged() {
    var theater = this.value;
    $('#thirdselectbox option').attr('hidden', true);
    $('#thirdselectbox option[data-theater="' + theater + '"]').attr('hidden', false);
    $("#thirdselectbox option[hidden!=hidden]").eq(0).prop("selected", true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="UserData">
  <h1>MyMovie-Ticket-Booking</h1>
  <select class="selectCity" id="selectCity">
            <option value="City">Select City</option>
            <option value="Bengaluru">Bengaluru</option>
            <option value="Hyderabad">Hyderabad</option>
            <option value="Guntur">Guntur</option>
            <option value="Ongole">Ongole</option>
           </select>
  <span id="welcome"> </span>
</div>
<div>
  <select id="secondselectbox"></select>
  <select id="thirdselectbox"></select>
</div>
```